# I want to be prepared for my fish

Tags: aquarium, fish, equipment

For some time, I've been obsessed with the idea of getting a pet. It took me some time to decide which one I really want, and I decided on fish. However, it needs some proper preparations like an aquarium, filter, and much more stuff that I don't really know about. So I want to read some information with comparisons and recommendations for a newbie. It would be great if you could share some resources. I came across [one](https://pickedbyfish.com), but actually, there is not that much information. Or if you could share your own experience, that would be great. 
Anyway thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. I'm very glad you're responsible and research the needs of your future pets before buying them. Here is a list of the [most upvoted questions concerning aquariums](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium?tab=Votes) on our site. You can find many common problems and solutions there, like how big should the aquarium be for how many fishes and how to best cycle your aquarium befor you add your fishes.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing a fish keeper should know, especially a new person to the hobby, is knowing about the nitrogen cycle. I do not know if your do know about that already, but I will still give you a link to a website about it. The website will talk about important information like nitrite, nitrate, and ammonia in fish tanks. You do want to set up a fish tank before you get the fish. Do not set it up on the day you do get your new fish. This is very important. The website you should go visit is https://www.aquariumcoop.com/blogs/aquarium/nitrogen-cycle

What fish are you planning on buying? When you thought of a fish you want, make sure to do research on what it needs to thrive in your tank. Information you should gather on the fish you want would be, the temperature it thrives in, the tank size it needs, and ph levels of water it can thrive in.

Comment: When you set up your tank, let us know the results of how it came out. I remember when I set up a tank with new gravel, my water in the tank was very cloudy. I did some research and found out that they did have liquids at Petsmart and Petco to fix that. I bought a liquid that you pour in the water to help reduce and remove that cloudy water. It did help a lot. I just wanted to tell you this if the same happens to you. I have another website you could visit. https://www.aqueon.com/articles/how-to-fix-cloudy-tank-water-for-a-new-fish-tank

Comment: you can click the "edit" at the bottom of your answer and add this comment to your answer. This would be more readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting a few red cherry shrimp for a starter may be good and a few neon tetras! make sure the lights have a timer on your tank or else they may get weak and sick. Possibly having a catfish in your tank may help.